# Is there a maximum range which an npc will wander?

Tags: terraria

This isn't a "how do I stop npcs from wandering?" question - I want to build one of the npcs homes a bit further away from the rest, and was hoping to build it close enough so the npc will still wander into the town sometimes.

So - is there a specific maximum range which an npc will wander?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Whenever NPC wanders to far from their house, they will automatically 
Teleport to their respective house.

Answer (score -2):

No there is not. NPC's can walk freely, if there is a space they can't walk into and get out of they won't walk there. So basically make a simple room with 2 low and 2 wide blocks mined on the outside of the house (both sides if you have 2 doors)

Comment: I think I got the punctuation right on that, but it's seriously hard to tell.

Comment: Okay, I'm done attempting to improve your posts.  Punctuation.  It is your friend.  Capitalization is also, but only in moderation.

Comment: You seem to have some good, useful knowledge for this site, but you *really* need to put more effort into your questions/answers. Make them readable and put some time into thinking about how you're presenting them, and you'll get a great reception here.